# panda dataframe column values in list format

Tags: python, pandas, date

For some reason, one of my dataframe column is filled with lists as its value.

```
(ex): "Book Date" - [01/20/2018]
```

I've tried to make it into a string by applying both str(x) and ''.join(x) method but it doesn't work.

```
df['Book Date'] = df['Book Date'].map(lambda x: ''.join(x))
```

Could you please let me know what I should do and how to avoid this in the first place?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you paste some sample input?

Comment: Your entity seems to have a datatype of `O` so why don't you simply replace `[` and `]`? Isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use apply + join() and map() in order to convert your list to strings first.

Example DataFrame:

```
  >>> df1
      Book Date
1  [01/20/2018]
2  [01/22/2018]
```

Result:

```
>>> df1['Book Date'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))
1    01/20/2018
2    01/22/2018
Name: Book Date, dtype: object
```

OR

You could convert your list to str with `astype(str)` and then use replace to remove  `[ ]`  & `'`.

```
>>> df1['Book Date'].astype(str).str.replace('\[|\]|\'', '')
1    01/20/2018
2    01/22/2018
Name: Book Date, dtype: object
```

Comment: The astype method worked and now i can continue with my project <3 thank you!!

Comment: @JiwonJessicaKim, Glad to Know it worked for you, if the answers really useful you can accept  this answer.